Can pulsar consumer subscribe to partitioned topic with partition N by regexp?
I have simple pulsar consumer
pulsar_client.subscribe( topic=re.compile('persistent://public/default/some_topic_[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+1$'), subscription_name=consumer_group, consumer_type=ConsumerType.KeyShared, initial_position=InitialPosition.Earliest, consumer_name="con_1", start_message_id_inclusive=True )
I have already created a topic called 'some_topic_123' with 2 partitions.
I expected the consumer to subscribe to the topic like 'some_topic_123-partition-1'.
However, this did not happen, as the consumer successfully subscribed to the topic without a partition.
Is it possible for my situation?
P.S.: Sorry for my English.
I tried to set different types of regular expressions in the topic without success. I came across this GitHub issue - https://github.com/apache/pulsar/discussions/20716?ysclid=lv6lklt74f904311326 - but it did not help me
